# linking elf library failure on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, elf

i try use elf library to write some code on Ubuntu.

however, it has compile error and i have no idea what's wrong.

please help me, thanks.

```
sudo apt-get install libelf-dev

$ gcc -O3 -Wall -lelf test.c
/tmp/ccRqW5Qo.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text.startup+0xa): undefined reference to `elf_version'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

This is code of test.c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <libelf.h>

int main(void)
{
        elf_version(EV_CURRENT);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong order for command line parameters. You need to list source files *before* the libraries: `gcc -O3 -Wall test.c -lelf` would work.

Comment: yes, you are right! thanks a lot!